# Two specific irrational numbers summing to rational number that is not zero?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-functions, rationality-testing

There already exist pages that show how two irrational numbers can sum to a rational number. However, is there an actual example of this? What are some of irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x + y$ is rational and $x ≠ -y$ (for an example $\sqrt{2}$ and -$\sqrt{2}$ doesn't count)?

If there is an example of an irrational number $y$ for every irrational number $x$ that will sum to a rational number, does this property apply to all irrational numbers?

Comment: Add $1$ to both $x,y$.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$ are both irrational.

Comment: sorry, i should've worded my question better. I was looking for something like √x + √y = a/b

Comment: If so, add $a/2$ to both $x,y$, then divide by an integer $b$. For the second part, no such $y$ exists, consider $x = y$, $2y$ is never rational

Comment: So let us be clear. You are looking for $\,x\,$ irrational, $\,y\,$ irrational, and $\,z:=x+y\,$ rational. What about picking any $\,x\,$ irrational and $\,z\,$ rational and then $\,y=z-x\,$ will be irrational. Am I right?

Comment: Even if $\pi+e$ were rational (what we cannot currently rule out) , we would not really get any "nontrivial" solution because if we consider Somos comment , we could write $z$ as $x+(z-x)$. Whether a "surprising" example exists is unknown, perhaps we can say more if the numbers have to be algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:
$$\frac 1{\sqrt n-1}-\frac1{\sqrt n+1}=\frac 2{n-1},$$
so choose $n$ such that $\sqrt n$ is irrational.

Comment: These two are conjugates, with minimal polynomial $(n-1)x^2 - 2x - 1$, so they will also multiply together to $1/(n-1)$.

Comment: Yes,  but it yields an example for the O.P.'s question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x \in \mathbb R$ and any $q \in \mathbb Q$, since $\mathbb R$ contains $\mathbb Q$, $y = q-x$ will satisfy $y+x\in \mathbb Q$.

For any [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), it is possible to find the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)) over $\mathbb Q$ and thus the algebraic conjugates of the number, a pile of numbers that, along with $x$, both add up to a rational number *and* multiply together to a rational number!

Bad news though: the algebraic conjugate of $\sqrt{2}$ specifically is $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: well that was quick.  What'd I do?